# How to add subtitles choices to MP4

Tags: mp4, software-recommendation, subtitles

So I have a Mp4 file, and I want to **add multiples subtitles choices** to it that will stay forever. A bit like how YouTube, like there are the subtitles choices, and you select which one you want or none if you want none.

The problem is that I don't found how to do it.

I tried with **VLC**, but it doesn't add the subtitles as a choice it just put them on the video. I've also made some research, but it's always the same over and over.

So if you know how to do it or have a **website/software** (free is better) that does it, it'll be very welcome.

Comment: I've read this several times & I cannot quite figure out what it is you want. VLC can be set to favour a single language for subtitles, but it is a global parameter, which doesn't work quite so well if you watch foreign & domestic videos, some needing subs & some not. Toggling on/off is but a single key command away for those.

Comment: What I actually want is the possibility to choose between multiple subtitles language when I open the video. And this on all possible platforms, like VLC, Microsoft built in app etc. But I think that VLC only add one subtitle choice.

Comment: Subtitle choice depends on the video supplier - eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxeGG.png You switch on/off with Shift/S & cycle with V, or pick one directly from the menu, or set up your default in prefs.

Comment: Yeah, the picture is exactly what I want to do with my video. But is it possible to add multiple subtitles choices with VLC convert ?

Comment: If you have the subs files, just put them in the same folder as the video, with the same filename base. VLC will just find them.